# query multiple strings in a site text field database

Tags: sql, database, xquery

This is just a thought, but I have a standard website sql database I am trying to collect data from, but there is no way to access the SQL command line or bulk-query data. All I have to work with is the website's GUI with some text field options like "title" or "generic_ID" i can search individual ID's.

Is there a way of using sql code in one of the text fields to allow for multiple queries at once? For example, if the text field for "generic_ID" is asking for 1 ID, could I write something like:

```
"1234" AND "5678"
```

and get a query response for both of those IDs?

Comment: Do you want `in`:  `generic_ID in (1234, 5678)`?

Comment: It depends on how well the coder who built the website understood the dangers of SQL injection. If they did their job, then what you want to do should be impossible.

Comment: Well, the problem is I only have a text field to work with. is there a way of getting the text filed to read the string entered as multiple enteries.

Comment: Right, I dont want to do a SQL injection, just stack multiple query calls in a single text box, but is sounds like it is not really possible.